# How do I fix very slow/choppy experience with an ATI Radeon HD 5850 xtreme?

Tags: 11.04, ati, 64-bit

I've just installed ubuntu 11.04 64 bit and the gui feels really slow and choppy.
Running `glxgears` for example feels like I'm killing my pc because everything becomes really choppy and it looks like I don't even get 1 fps in glxgears. But in the console it says i get about 4.200 fps.

I've tried installing the latest driver manually with this guide: http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Natty_Installation_Guide. It didn't help.

I also tried this: http://www.jondev.net/articles/Ubuntu_11.04_choppy_or_slow. Didn't help either.

So right now I have Catalyst 11.5 installed via the [x-updates](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) ppa.

If you have any ideas, then please help me because at the moment my ubuntu installation is hardly usable (oh, btw. reinstalling it didn't help).

Answer (score 1):

I Also have issues with slow gui and video on my ati athlon64 system the solution I have found to work best is to modify this file `/etc/pulse/default.pa`

find this line

`load-module module-udev-detect`

and replace it with this

`load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this but it didn't change anything and so I changed it back to `load-module module-udev-detect` and did another another reboot. Somehow compiz runs smoothly now and (almost) everything is fine and I can watch 1080p videos with vlc again for example. But certain things, like changing the desktop wallpaper or running glxgears/fgl-glxgears are still very slow and choppy.